# Vue: V-select dropdown keeps triggering keyboard to popup on iOS browser

Tags: vue.js

I am using `v-select` (Vuetify) as a dropdown component.  When I click the dropdown to expand the option, it does but it also has a blinking cursor on the input line for the ability type and search the dropdown options if you don't want to scroll through them.  The issue is that this is automatically triggering the iOS keyboard to come up and it's covering half the screen.
I tried passing the prop `:disabled=true` but this just prevents the dropdown from even expanding.  Is there anyways to disable this without disabling the dropdown functionality?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. A quick question: If you were able to disable the keyboard, how would the user be able to type anything?

Comment: Hey Stephen!  I actually don't want a user to type anything -- I am using it for the dropdown effect and to click the dropdown option.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but are you using some props? Try to reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com)

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong component

Comment: @Traxo thanks!  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrZVXZ <-- I just saved the codepen.  You can check it here.  Once you trigger the dropdown, the cursor starts blinking so you can type in there which is why I don't want

Comment: There is no `vuetify` in your codepen. You need to reproduce properly using the link I provided if it's related to `vuetify`. If related to the component you are using in the codepen (i.e. `vue-select`) then reformat question and remove `vuetify` tag.

Comment: @Traxo my sincere apologies.  I thought I vue-select/vuetify were same thing but apparently vue-select is also a solo component outside of Vuetify which is different (https://vue-select.org) .  I will remove Vuetify from the tag.  Thanks again and sorry

Comment: sounds like you need to use the single-line prop... given the docs and samples there https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects

Comment: @JorgeCampos i actually just found it ..it's the `searchable` prop, which is defaulted to `true` . It allows you to type in the input box to search the dropdown options so I just had to pass in `:searchable="false"` and that resolved it

Comment: Awesome. Can you please add it as an answer and mark it as accepted? It may help others in the future. :) cheers,